# Inject JUnit 5 parameters into @BeforeEach

Tags: java, junit5, parameterized

I'm currently writing some parameterized tests with JUnit 5 (using `@EnumSource`).

I'm trying to run a method before each test using the same parameter as the test itself, but JUnit fails with `No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [...enum] in method [...beforeEach]`.

Is there a way to achieve this, or should I just make a private method to call at the beginning of each test?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. I'll just call a method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is not currently possible.

I resolved this by calling a method with test parameters at the beginning of each test.